# Cancelling Aysnchronous stored procedure

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net, asynchronous

I am running a long running stored procedure that user can cancel. I am using Backgroundworker component along with BeginExecuteReader method of ado.net

everything seems to work fine, but even when i cancel the stored procedure, the database is still running the proc

Is there a way to cancel the actual job on the database server itself ? I can see that we can use kill command, but that needs the job id.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SqlCommand.Cancel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.cancel.aspx)

Comment: that worked, but as soon as i cancel it, it calls the callback method, and throws exceptions saying "A severe error occured on the current command .". Is there a way to check if the command was cancelled ? the is Completed property of the IAsyncResult is true until EndExecuteReader method is called.